# Deploying static js and html file on web server using http-server and forever

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

I have a folder on ubuntu server which has a bunch of d3, js files. I want to display the html file on the browser running on the server.

I have got both node.js and http-server and forever installed.

I tried first with just http-server using nohup to run it in background.

```
 nohup http-server -p 8000 -a 10.1.152.145 &
```

THis works and open up the directory structure on the browser. On clicking the html file there it opens up the visualization. I however want the html to be directly displayed on browser without havinng to click on it.

I then read forever is a better way to run a code in background on server so I did this:

```
forever start $(which http-server) -p 8000 -a 10.1.152.145 -d false
```

This doesn't give any error in bash, but when I got to

`10.1.152.145:8000` on browser it doesn't display any file directory and says access denied.

```
Access to 10.1.152.145 was denied You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403
```

Any help in fixing this?

Thanks